# Objective C - Get the name of a CTFont?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a CTFontRef, how can i get the font name as a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read this http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFontRef/Reference/reference.html

There are methods defined for example.

```
Getting Font Names
CTFontCopyPostScriptName
CTFontCopyFamilyName
CTFontCopyFullName
CTFontCopyDisplayName
CTFontCopyName
CTFontCopyLocalizedName
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be a bit more specific about what you mean by "font name". The PostScript name? Display name? Family name?

In any case, this is how you'd go about it:

```
NSString *postScriptName = 
             [(NSString *)CTFontCopyPostScriptName(fontRef) autorelease];
NSLog(@"postScriptName == %@", postScriptName);
```

`CFStringRef` and `NSString` are toll-free bridged (see [Toll-Free Bridged Types](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html)).